# Drools 6 Fusion Notification

Tags: drools, complex-event-processing

We are working in a very complex solution using drools 6 (Fusion) and I would like your opinion about best way to read Objects created during the correlation results over time.
My first basic approach was to read Working Memory every certain time, looking for new objects and reporting them to external Service (REST).
AgendaEventListener does not seems to be the "best" approach beacuse I dont care about most of the objects being inserted in working memory, so maybe, best approach would be to inject particular "object" in some sort of service inside DRL. Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a lot of options. In decreasing order of my preference:

1. AgendaEventListener is probably the solution requiring the smallest amount of LOC. It might be useful for other tasks as well; all you have on the negative side is one additional method call and a class test per inserted fact. Peanuts.
2. You can wrap the insert macro in a DRL function and collect inserted fact of class X in a global List. The problem you have here is that you'll have to pass the KieContext as a second parameter to the function call.
3. If the creation of a class X object is inevitably linked with its insertion into WM, you could add the registry of new objects into a static List inside class X, to be done in a factory method (or the constructor).
4. I'm putting your "basic approach" last because it requires much more cycles than the listener (#1) and tons of overhead for maintaining the set of X objects that have already been put to REST.

Comment: Thank you Laune for your suggestions. I also think that #4 is not the best way to go :D. I will give a try to number #2 that, at very first sight, is the one that will consume less resources.